# why is a signal-handler calling signal() in his method-body?

Tags: c, signals, daemon

In university we are currently learning about daemons and how to handle signals.
But why is the signal-handler calling signal()? In the main-method `signal(...)` is already being called. So to my understanding when `pkill -SIGUSR1` for example is sent to the thread the one `signal(...)`call in the main-method should be sufficient in catching and delegating to the handler. Maybe someone can explain.

In our textbook there is this example:

```
void sighandler (int sig) {
printf ("Caught signal %d\n", sig);
signal (SIGINT, sighandler);
signal (SIGALRM, sighandler);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv [], char *envp []) {

char buffer [1024];
int len;
signal (SIGINT, sighandler);
signal (SIGALRM, sighandler);
alarm (5);

for (len = 0; len < 10; len++)
 printf ("Counting %d...\n", len), sleep (1);

alarm (10);

while (1) {

 len = read (0, buffer, sizeof (buffer) - 1);

 if (len == -1) {
  perror ("read () failed");
  continue;
  }

 if (len == 0) {
  printf ("Exiting\n");
  exit (0);
  }

 buffer [len] = '\0';

 if (!strncmp (buffer, "exit", 4))
  exit (0);

 write (1, buffer, strlen (buffer));
  }
}
```

Comment: A bit OFFTOPIC but I can tell you for sure that it's better to not use standard functions in your `handlers`, if you need to output a message use `write()` instead of `printf`. At least you know this for the future and you won't do the same error as in the example.

Comment: *In our textbook there is this example:*  Ooof.  A ***textbook*** that does unsafe things like call `printf()` from a signal handler?!?

Comment: @AndrewHenle the prof. made the example : D

Comment: @real_G Wow, it's problematic if your professor does a mistake like that but whatever. Remember it for your future projects. I'm not sure about the `signal` inside the `handler`, so let's see if someone better prepared will help you with that part.

Comment: I guess he never read [this document](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188) then...  :-/

Comment: [The semantics when using signal to establish a signal handler vary across systems; do not use it for this purpose](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) Anyway, (on Linux) it establishes a one-shot handler, it has to be reinstalled after firing.

Comment: You probably shouldn't register signal handlers with `signal` in any code written in the last decade or so, maybe since the mid 90s.  Use `sigaction`.

Comment: The one-shot signal is a heritage of unix sytem5. BSD did not need it. Linux/libc can emulate both behaviours (by calling sigaction() with the appropiate parameters) , depending on _BSD_SOURCE, libc, and the phase of the moon. Anyway: you should always use `sigaction()` to avoid this mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer**

The code is re-installing the signal handlers so that subsequent SIGINTs and SIGALRMs invoke the same signal handler again.

Why?  Historically, some implementations of `signal()` *reset the signal disposition to the default* (SIG_DFL) upon invoking a user-defined signal handler, effectively making the signal handler a "one shot" affair.  Some did not do this.

Thus, a common practice was to have user-defined signal handlers re-install themselves to make the handler effectively permanent.  (On systems that did not reset disposition, this merely made the signal handler slightly less efficient by introducing a pointless syscall.)

`sigaction()`, the [successor to `signal()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html#tag_16_550_07) which was [standardized in POSIX.1-1988](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html#tag_16_540_11), resolves this ambiguity by providing a flag, SA_RESETHAND, to control whether or not the handler is reset.

---

**Aside**

The commenters above are quite right:  the code you are studying is a bad example.

Any use of `signal()` is dubious in modern, production-quality code.  That alone would not pass code review in many shops.

Even allowing `signal()`, the fact that the handler is not re-installed *right away*, before the `printf()`, is a bit odd.

`printf()` is not [async-signal-safe](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03).  In very simple toy programs it can be used without problems in a signal handler, but even this very example **is not safe**.  What if the `printf()` in the handler is called during the main loop's `printf()`?  What if that five second ALRM handler call interrupts an INT handler call?